# C# DataTable String Manipulation

Tags: c#, string, datatable, append, character

So I am using a DataTable and for loop to seperate a file by spaces/Tabs using the .split() Function in C#
to spererate the data in to seperate columns.

The issue I am having is some data has spaces in between the text of which I would like to keep as one column.

For Example:

```
ID   Product        Form        Amount 
XXX  XXX            XXX, XXX    XXX
```

the issue I am having is the Data gets split and makes the columns in correct like so:

```
ID   Product        Form        Amount
XXX  XXX            XXX,        XXX     XXX
```

I was wondering if there is a was to look in the previous column and check for say a comma in which case
I would like to append the previous and current columns together.

To put it into straight forward context unless someone has a better method:

I need to check the last character of a string (Column).

I need to then depending on if its a letter or (Comma or bracket) Add a new column to the datatable or 
append a column to previous column...

This is my current splitting code:

```
        Char[] seperator = new Char[] {'\t'};

        DataTable tbl = new DataTable(fileName);

        MessageBox.Show("There are: " + rows.Length + " rows.");

        if (rows.Length != 0 )
        {
            foreach (string headerCol in rows[0].Split(seperator))
            {
                tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(headerCol));
            }
            if (tbl.Columns.Count <= 20)
            {
                for (int i = tbl.Columns.Count; i < 15; i++)
                {
                    tbl.Columns.Add("col " + i);
                }
            }
        }

        if (rows.Length > 1)
        {
            for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < rows.Length; rowIndex++)
            {
                var newRow = tbl.NewRow();
                var cols = rows[rowIndex].Split(    );

                try
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Columns: " + cols.Length + " is fixed size: " + cols.IsFixedSize, "Column Data");

                        // If cannot find column then ignore and fill with blank...
                        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols.Length; colIndex++)
                        {
                            newRow[colIndex] = cols[colIndex];
                           // MessageBox.Show(cols[colIndex],"Col Index");
                        }

                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex, "Error"); 
                } finally
                {

                }

                tbl.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show us the splitting code

Comment: Do a C# string Replace() on column values to remove spaces

Comment: If the columns are separated by tabs, why do you split by comma or spaces?

Comment: The data I am extracting from is really messy with a lot of spaces and tabs I am currently splitting the columns  by tabs but some of the data has say (injection, 100mg) or say (tablet (100mg)) so I would like to look for commas and brackets in order to keep certain parts of the data together in a column. Cheers guys.

Comment: Ryan I ended up using Replace() a few times to remove chars that caused a problem... Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the solution using the .Replace() function suggested by Ryan.

I just carried it out a number of times for example.
.Replace(",\t", ",")
.Replace(", ", ",")

Of which fixed the data layout more efficiently than expected.